# HTML Form onclick call a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use an html Form to call a script, this already works, as the button "calculate" confirm (click), but my problem is that I want to do the calculation with the "enter" button. For example, if the "LMB" = 4000m then should be calculated without using the "calculate" button.

```
 <pre><em>
    <table class="fl">   

    <tr><td>LMB:</td><td><form>
   <input type="number" name="points" id="LMB"
   min="800" max="8500" step="1" size="8" value="3000"  onclick="uebergabe()">   </form>
     </td></tr>
    <tr><td>AT:</td><td><form>
   <input type="number" name="AT" id="AT"
   min="2" max="12" step="1" size="8"value="2"></form>
   </td></tr>
   <tr><td>A:</td><td><form>
   <input type="number" name="points" id="A"
   min="45" max="70" step="25" size="8" value="45"></form>
   </td></tr>
   <tr><td>Z:</td><td><form>
   <input type="number" name="points" id="Z"
   min="6" max="10" step="1" size="8" value="8"></form>
   <tr><td>WM:</td><td id="LMB"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>WM:</td><td id="WM"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>STB:</td><td id="STB"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>LS4:</td><td id="LS4"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>LS2:</td><td id="LS2"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>LS3:</td><td id="LS3"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>LS1:</td><td id="LS1"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>FS:</td><td id="FS"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>RT:</td><td id="RT"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Total:</td><td id="TOTAL"></td></tr>

    <tr><td></td><td><input type="button" id="taste" value="Berechnen"></td><td> </td></tr>

    </Table></em>
    window.onload = init;
    function init(){
    document.getElementById('taste').onclick = uebergabe;uebergabe();
}
    function uebergabe(){
    var Z = Number( document.getElementById('Z').value );
    var AT = Number( document.getElementById('AT').value );
    var LMB = Number( document.getElementById('LMB').value );
    var A = Number( document.getElementById('A').value );
    if (A>70 || A<45){ alert('Geben Sie fuer "A" einen Wert von 45 oder 70 
    ein'); return;}
    if (Z>10 || Z<6){ alert('Geben Sie einen Wert zwischen 6 und 10 ein');   return;}
   if (AT>10 || AT<-10){ alert('Geben Sie einen Wert zwischen 2 und 12 ein'); return;}
if (AT==0){ alert('Geben Sie einen Wert zwischen 2 und 12 ein'); return;}
if (LMB>8500 || LMB<800){ alert(' Geben Sie einen Wert zwischen 800 und 8500 ein '); return;}
if (STB>500 || STB<-500){ alert('STB sollte zwischen 500 und 1200 sein )'); return;}
var WM = LMB - Z;
var STB = WM / AT;
var LS4 = STB - (23.775 * AT) - 426.93;
var LS2 = (3.732 * STB) - (3.732 * LS4) - (69.975 * AT) + (A * AT) - (2 * A) + 80 + Z - 1524.9;
var LS3 = (3.864 * STB) - (3.864 * LS4) - (72.45 * AT) + (1.035 * A * AT) - (2.07 * A) - 1652.58;
var LS1 = LMB - 380 - LS2;
var FS = LMB;
var RT = (AT - 2) * A + 80 + 54 + 60 + Z;
var TOTAL = LS1 + LS2 + LS3 + LS4;

var LS2a = (3.732 * STB) - (3.732 * LS4) - (69.975 * AT) + (A * AT) - (2 * A) + 80 + Z - 1524.9;
var LS1a = LMB - 380 - LS2a;
var LS4a = STB - (23.775 * AT) - 426.93;
var LS3a = (3.864 * STB) - (3.864 * LS4a) - (72.45 * AT) + (1.035 * A * AT) - (2.07 * A) - 1652.58;
document.getElementById('WM').innerHTML = WM.toFixed(0);
document.getElementById('STB').innerHTML = STB.toFixed(0);
document.getElementById('LS4').innerHTML = LS4.toFixed(0);
document.getElementById('LS2').innerHTML = LS2.toFixed(0);
document.getElementById('LS3').innerHTML = LS3.toFixed(0);
document.getElementById('LS1').innerHTML = LS1.toFixed(0);
document.getElementById('LS1a').innerHTML = LS1a.toFixed(0);
document.getElementById('LS2a').innerHTML = LS2a.toFixed(0);
document.getElementById('LS3a').innerHTML = LS3a.toFixed(0);
document.getElementById('LS4a').innerHTML = LS4a.toFixed(0);
document.getElementById('FS').innerHTML = FS.toFixed(0);
document.getElementById('RT').innerHTML = RT.toFixed(0);
document.getElementById('TOTAL').innerHTML = TOTAL.toFixed(0);
}
</script>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you to all, it's really helpful, I tried all the solutions, and finally I use;
It works but not with the enter button, only with the "Tab", when I use the "Enter" are all values return to the set value. Why?
My solution;
<form>
   <input type="number" name="points" id="LMB"
   min="800" max="8500" step="1" size="8" value="5000" onchange="uebergabe(this.value)" >
</form>

Answer (score 0):

You should use the onSubmit-Event on the Form:

```
document.getElementById('the-id-you-need-to-add-to-the-form').onsubmit = uebergabe;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to open your `script`-tag, so it would never be evaluated as JS-code. To solve that, you'd simply need to do this;

```
<pre>
  <em>
    <!--WAY TO LONG HTML HERE-->
  </em>
  <script>
    //MORE JS CODE
    function uebergabe(){
      //uebergabe function
    }
  </script>
</pre>
```

Besides that, you are defining both in your HTML and JS that `uebergabe` should be called when the input is clicked, you should remove one of the two.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct JS (errors are commented on the code)

```
// The script tag was missing
window.onload = init;

function init() {
    document.getElementById('taste').onclick = uebergabe;uebergabe();
}

function uebergabe() {
    var Z = Number( document.getElementById('Z').value );
    var AT = Number( document.getElementById('AT').value );
    var LMB = Number( document.getElementById('LMB').value );
    var A = Number( document.getElementById('A').value );

    //String must be in one line
    if (A>70 || A<45){ alert('Geben Sie fuer "A" einen Wert von 45 oder 70 ein'); return;}
    if (Z>10 || Z<6){ alert('Geben Sie einen Wert zwischen 6 und 10 ein');   return;}
    if (AT>10 || AT<-10){ alert('Geben Sie einen Wert zwischen 2 und 12 ein'); return;}
    if (AT==0){ alert('Geben Sie einen Wert zwischen 2 und 12 ein'); return;}
    if (LMB>8500 || LMB<800){ alert(' Geben Sie einen Wert zwischen 800 und 8500 ein '); return;}
    if (STB>500 || STB<-500){ alert('STB sollte zwischen 500 und 1200 sein )'); return;}

    var WM = LMB - Z;
    var STB = WM / AT;
    var LS4 = STB - (23.775 * AT) - 426.93;
    var LS2 = (3.732 * STB) - (3.732 * LS4) - (69.975 * AT) + (A * AT) - (2 * A) + 80 + Z - 1524.9;
    var LS3 = (3.864 * STB) - (3.864 * LS4) - (72.45 * AT) + (1.035 * A * AT) - (2.07 * A) - 1652.58;
    var LS1 = LMB - 380 - LS2;
    var FS = LMB;
    var RT = (AT - 2) * A + 80 + 54 + 60 + Z;
    var TOTAL = LS1 + LS2 + LS3 + LS4;
    var LS2a = (3.732 * STB) - (3.732 * LS4) - (69.975 * AT) + (A * AT) - (2 * A) + 80 + Z - 1524.9;
    var LS1a = LMB - 380 - LS2a;
    var LS4a = STB - (23.775 * AT) - 426.93;
    var LS3a = (3.864 * STB) - (3.864 * LS4a) - (72.45 * AT) + (1.035 * A * AT) - (2.07 * A) - 1652.58;

    document.getElementById('WM').innerHTML = WM.toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('STB').innerHTML = STB.toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('LS4').innerHTML = LS4.toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('LS2').innerHTML = LS2.toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('LS3').innerHTML = LS3.toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('LS1').innerHTML = LS1.toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('LS1a').innerHTML = LS1a.toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('LS2a').innerHTML = LS2a.toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('LS3a').innerHTML = LS3a.toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('LS4a').innerHTML = LS4a.toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('FS').innerHTML = FS.toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('RT').innerHTML = RT.toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('TOTAL').innerHTML = TOTAL.toFixed(0);
```

}

About HTML some ID's were missing

```
<tr><td>LS1a:</td><td id="LS1a"></td></tr> <!-- LS1a was missing -->
<tr><td>LS2a:</td><td id="LS2a"></td></tr> <!-- LS2a was missing -->
<tr><td>LS3a:</td><td id="LS3a"></td></tr> <!-- LS3a was missing -->
<tr><td>LS4a:</td><td id="LS4a"></td></tr> <!-- LS4a was missing -->
```

Comment: You should consider to split your uebergabe function, for example to extract the check on the input

Answer (score -1):

Bind the required field to the onchange event handler (or the oninput, according to your needs).

For example:
document.getElementById('LMB').onchange = ...

For more details see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp